# Differential equation $(u')^2(1+\alpha u^2)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find $u$ such that (with constant $\alpha>0$ and $u'\ge 0$)

$$(u')^2(1+\alpha u^2)=1$$

By applying $u=\frac{\sinh(x)}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$, I found 
$$\cosh^2(x)=\sqrt{\alpha}.dx$$

and then $$d\left(\frac{2x+\sinh(2x)}{4}\right)=\sqrt{\alpha}.dx$$

not sure what to do after that.

$2x+\sinh(2x)=(4\sqrt{\alpha}).t+C$, and then let 
$$f_\alpha(x)=\frac{2x+\sinh(x)}{4\sqrt{\alpha}}$$

Then $$u(t)=\sinh\left(f_\alpha^{-1}(t)\right)$$

But is there any way to have a more friendly expression for $u$, using usual functions ?

Comment: Assuming that $\alpha\gt0$ and provided you replace $4\alpha$ in the last formula by $\pm4\sqrt{\alpha}$, this is correct and one cannot go much further. (If $\alpha\lt0$, this is another story.)

Comment: @Did, so I can write my solution as something like $\sinh(f^{-1}(t))$ with $f:t\mapsto x+\sinh(x)$. But I can't do something more using usual functions ?

Comment: Forget usual functions !

Comment: Compare "one cannot go much further" and "can't (I) do something more?"

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici And now, if I need some asymptotic behaviour of $u$, how can I do ?

Comment: Your final expression is $$x=\frac{1}{2} u \sqrt{\alpha  u^2+1}+\frac{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\alpha } u\right)}{2
   \sqrt{\alpha }}$$ If you need to inverse it, only numerical methods will be able to do something.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ok, so $u\approx \sqrt{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{\alpha}}}$

Comment: @Xoff. You got it ! I was about to post this answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

You could notice that the equation is separable since

$$\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2 (1+\alpha u^2)=1$$

can write $$\frac{dx}{du}=\pm \sqrt {1+\alpha u^2}$$ Now, use user121049's suggestion for an appropriate change of variable for the integration of the rhs.

**Added later to this answer**

The final solution to this problem is $$x=\frac{1}{2} u \sqrt{\alpha  u^2+1}+\frac{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\alpha } u\right)}{2    \sqrt{\alpha }}$$ Concerning the asymptotic behavior, the OP showed by himsel that, for large values of $x$ can be derived the approximation $$ u \simeq \frac{\sqrt{2x} }{\sqrt[4]{\alpha }}$$ It is possible to obtain a better approximation developing the rhs as a Taylor series built at $x=\infty$. This leads to $$x \simeq \frac{\sqrt{\alpha } u^2}{2}+\frac{\log (4 \alpha )+2 \log (u)+1}{4 \sqrt{\alpha }}$$ Reversing this last expression leads to $$u \simeq \frac{\sqrt{W\left(\frac{1}{2} e^{4 \sqrt{\alpha } x-1}\right)}}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}
  }$$ which is much better.

Comment: @enzotib. Thanks for editing !

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure what to do after that...

Comment: The integration of $\sqrt {1+\alpha u^2}$ is very simple if you change variable as suggested by user121049.

Comment: Yes, it is the next step that is difficult to me. See my edit in the question.

Comment: Please, define $\sqrt{\alpha} u = \sinh(y)$ and integrate wrt $y$. $x$ is in the lhs only. You are almost done. You will end soon ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Take square root then substitute $\sqrt{\alpha} u = \sinh(x)$